# Codeigniter .htaccess not ignoring directories

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a website built on codeigniter and am trying to get the PP IPN working with it.  I have looked at a few CI specific libraries, but want to have a stand alone IPN file.

Basically, I have CI installed in the website root and I have another directory 'pp', also in the root.

I'm trying to test the IPN using Paypal's sandbox, but it's returning a 404, I also can't access the file directly.

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
XSendFile on
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymlinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

### Canonicalize codeigniter URLs
RewriteRule ^(index(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]

# Removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.net/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|pp|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# Without mod_rewrite, route 404's to the front controller
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Here's hoping it's something really obvious!

Thanks,

Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `pp` directory exists, you could just put an htaccess file in that directory and just have:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

in it by itself, and any rules in the main htaccess file would get ignored. If your paypal stuff already has rewrite rules in an htaccess file in the `pp` directory, you may want to look into those rules as the cause of the 404.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have mod_rewrite.c enabled. If not, that .htaccess will always give 404. (Sorry I couldn't make this a comment, don't have the rep).